# Rsync for perfect copy: softlinks become..dir

Tags: rsync, symlink

I do a "clone" from one mounted disk to other disk mounted remotely.
I will cal them local and remote.
Local is slackware,and remote ubuntu
On local

```
df -h /mnt/
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   49G  4.3G   43G  10% /mnt
```

On remote

```
 df -h /media/ubuntu/1c34a414-9fa2-4bfe-a57c-7f82f1b31b29
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk1p2   57G  7.2G   47G  14% /media/ubuntu/1c34a414-9fa2-4bfe-a57c-7f82f1b31b29
```

I see rsync is not done the things properly,after use this command
from local

```
cd /mnt
 for i in * ;do rsync -avP --delete --ignore-errors $i/ 192.168.0.75:/media/ubuntu/1c34a414-9fa2-4bfe-a57c-7f82f1b31b29/$i; done
```

I see for example on local

```
file bin
bin: symbolic link to usr/bin
```

and on remote..

```
file /media/ubuntu/1c34a414-9fa2-4bfe-a57c-7f82f1b31b29/bin/
/media/ubuntu/1c34a414-9fa2-4bfe-a57c-7f82f1b31b29/bin/: directory
```

I want bin destroyed on remote and it must become(as on local) a symbolic link
Which option for rsync?
Using:

`rsync -avPl
 rsync -rvPl`

doesn't work

Comment: Did you use `rsync -l`?

Comment: Of course,and don't work

Comment: You say "of course", and yet in your question you say you used `rsync -avP`; `-a` does not imply `-l` which explicitly is used to copy links as links.  I have tested this for another question involving `rsync` yesterday and it is fresh in my mind; I am not able to replicate your stated behavior of `-l` not copying a link as a link.

Comment: I have added then,the -l,options,and bin on remote,is still a dir,so don't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-l` (`-links`) option is implied by `-a` (`--archive`) but you also need -K (`--keep-dirlinks`) so that target directories are allowed to be symlinks. You may find that you also need `--delete-before` to correct the existing structure.

```
rsync -avKP --delete --ignore-errors src/ 192.168.0.75:dst/
```

Looking more closely at your original code, you're iterating across what I now see is the top level of your server, including `/bin` and `/usr`. In this instance `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`, but your code passes this to `rsync` with `$i/`, which equates to `/bin/`. So `rsync` never sees this as a symlink because your `$i/` has already dereferenced it.

Removing your `for` loop and letting `rsync` handle the full directory tree itself will allow it to see the top-level symlink and transfer it correctly.

Comment: sorry but doesn't work if the bin already exist on remote and is a directory

Comment: @elbarna please use the `--delete-before` option

Comment: I used but nothing change

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice "workaround"

Instead of did

```
cd /mnt
 for i in * ;do rsync -avXHhP --delete --ignore-errors $i/ 192.168.0.75:/media/ubuntu/1c34a414-9fa2-4bfe-a57c-7f82f1b31b29/$i; done
```

I do

```
rsync --avXHhP --delete --ignore-errors /mnt/ 192.168.0.75:/media/ubuntu/1c34a414-9fa2-4bfe-a57c-7f82f1b31b29 ; done
```

And work,the dir are identical even on symlinks

Edit: I correct with -avXHhP,which is more good for backup bootable

Comment: Oh I see what you were doing. In your original case `rsync` couldn't have seen the top level symlink because you had already dereferenced it. This is a consequence of your script, not of `rsync`.